# The system cannot find the file specified - at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection.LoadStoreFromFile

Tags: c#, console

Using a Console application to create http request.
Getting error - "The system cannot find the file specified" at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection.Import(certificateFilePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

certificateFilePath is absolute path of .p12 certificate